# Ionic have to save state after button action

Tags: javascript, arrays, ionic-framework

Can someone please help me with some ionic code.

I have a list of items which i am getting from a api and displaying using ngFor, with a button "complete"

What i want to do is when someone click on "complete",  the item should move to the complete tab and when the app refreshes the item should stay in the complete tab not to display again under the incomplete.

Thanks

Comment: Where is your code

Comment: When someone clicks "complete", does that update a status via your API server so that when anyone gets these complete "items" again from the API they see things as completed?

Comment: @BRass no it does not update the status of the api

Comment: OK.  If this is a local-only "complete" status for this user, you plan to write these complete statuses to some sort of local storage I assume?  (i.e. https://ionicframework.com/docs/storage/).